# Istio: HTTP Authorization: verify user is the resource owner

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, authorization, microservices, istio

Looking into using Istio to handle Authorization for an application built on a microservices architecture in Kubernetes.

One thing we're looking to accomplish is to decouple the authorization of a service by utilizing Istio Authorization.

Our API Gateway (Kong) will handle the verification/parsing of the JWT tokens and pass along any required attributes (usernames, groups, roles etc) as headers e.g. x-username: homer@somewhere.com (abstracts that from the services)

What we want to accomplish is along with verifying based on roles etc we also want to ensure that the x-username is also the owner of the resource e.g. if they are accessing:

```
/user/{userID}/resource
```

That would mean if userId matches the value of the x-username header we can continue serving the request, otherwise we'll send a 401 etc

Is there a way to configure this as part of Istio Authorization?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is attribute based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)). Look into authorization engines e.g. Axiomatics that plug straight into Kong and provides that level of access control (ownership check).

- Kong authorization [handler on GitHub](https://github.com/ioannis-iordanidis/kong-axiomatics-plugin)
- Technical [webcast](https://ma.axiomatics.com/acton/media/10529/open-source-api-gateways-and-dynamic-authorization-working-with-kong) on the integration

You could also choose to call Axiomatics from Isitio using an adapter based on Istio's [authorization template](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/authorization/).

Policies in Axiomatics are written using either XACML or [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)) which are the 2 OASIS standards for ABAC / fine-grained authorization.

You could easily write a condition along the lines of:

```
rule checkOwner{
    deny
    condition not(owner==user.uid)
}
```

BTW you probably want to send back a 403 rather than 401. The latter refers to failed authentication.